# Inserting formula giving error.. Excel found unreadable content in "ab.xlsx". Do you want to recover the

Tags: c#, openxml

my requirement to is to insert formula for a cell. i am using below method to insert formula. And its inserting formula corectly and formula working fine. 
but when i insert formula my excel file got corrpted and showing the message

> "Excel found unreadable content in "exceltemplate.xlsx"

Do you want to recover the contents of...". 
I searched lot,but not getting resolved.
Please help to resolve this

```
public void InsertFormula(string filepath, string SheetName, string strCellIndex, string strFormula)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, true))
    {
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == SheetName);
        if (sheets.Count() == 0)
        {
            // The specified worksheet does not exist.
            return;
        }
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheets.First().Id);
        Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

        Row row1 = new Row()
        {
            RowIndex = (UInt32Value)4U,
            Spans = new ListValue<StringValue>()
        };

        Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = strCellIndex };
        CellFormula cellformula = new CellFormula();
        cellformula.Text = strFormula;
        cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
        CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();
        cellValue.Text = "0";
        cell.Append(cellformula);
        cell.Append(cellValue);
        row1.Append(cell);

        sheetData.Append(row1);
        worksheet.Save();
        document.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *exceltemplate.**aspx*** doesn't sound right...

Comment: sry.. its .xlsx @DanielHilgarth

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with the function.

1st problem is that you explicitly set the RowIndex to 4U. The cell that you're assigning the formula to has to be on row 4, say cell C4. Since the cell reference is passed in as a parameter (strCellIndex), that's not guaranteed.

And even if you fixed that, we have the next (and more insidious) problem...

2nd problem is a little harder to fix. The Row class has to be inserted in order within the SheetData class (as child objects), ordered by RowIndex. Let's assume you still want RowIndex to be hard-coded as 4U. This means if the existing Excel file has rows 2, 3 and 7, you have to insert the Row class behind the Row class with RowIndex 3. This is important, otherwise Excel will puke blood (as you've already experienced).

The solution to the 2nd problem requires a little more work. Consider the functions InsertAt(), InsertBefore() and InsertAfter() of the SheetData class (or most of the Open XML SDK classes actually). Iterate through the child classes of SheetData till you find a Row class with a RowIndex greater than the Row class you're inserting. Then use InsertBefore().

I will leave you with the fun task of error checking, such as if there are no Row classes to begin with, or all Row classes have RowIndex-es less than your to-be-inserted Row class, or (here's the fun one) an existing Row class with the same RowIndex as the Row class you want to insert.

Comment: i removed rowindex 4U,now passing rowindex dynamically. its working beautiful. thanq very much.